# Incorrect format in XML output file and I'm not sure why

Tags: xml, plsql, oracle11g, format

Below is a simple example of getting data from the Oracle 11g database (I'm using the dual table in this simple example) into a flat file.

I'm expecting the below format in the file.

```
<message>
  <production>
    <prodCategoryType>test type 1</prodCategoryType>
    <prodStatusType>prod status 1</prodStatusType>
  </production>
</message>
<message>
 <production>
  <prodCategoryType>test type 2</prodCategoryType>
  <prodStatusType>prod status 2</prodStatusType>
 </production>
</message>
```

but I'm getting the below instead, which seems to be missing start message and production tag and putting a strange **on>** in the middle.

```
<message>
   <production>
     <prodCategoryType>test type 1</prodCategoryType>
     <prodStatusType>prod status 1</prodStatusType>
   </production>
</message>
on>
     <prodCategoryType>test type 2</prodCategoryType>
     <prodStatusType>prod status 2</prodStatusType>
  </production>
</message>
```

Am I doing something wrong???

```
DECLARE

 l_file    UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
 l_clob    CLOB;
 l_buffer  VARCHAR2(32767);
 l_amount  BINARY_INTEGER := 32767;
 l_pos     INTEGER := 1;
 l_extract_dir               CONSTANT dba_directories.directory_name%TYPE:= 'REPORTS_OUT_DIR';   -- \\data2\data\download\d7prdv1\prsrepreports  


 l_xmltype XMLTYPE;
 l_domdoc dbms_xmldom.DOMDocument;
 l_root_node dbms_xmldom.DOMNode;     

 l_message_node            dbms_xmldom.DOMNode;

 l_production_element    dbms_xmldom.DOMElement;
 l_production_node       dbms_xmldom.DOMNode;

-- production XML elements, node, text
 l_prod_element                   dbms_xmldom.DOMElement;     
 l_prod_node         dbms_xmldom.DOMNode;
 l_prod_t_node          dbms_xmldom.DOMNode;
 l_prod_text          dbms_xmldom.DOMText;
 -- production XML elements, node, text, node

 CURSOR c_production
 IS SELECT 'test type 1',            as prodCategoryType
           'prod status 1'          as prodStatusType
    from dual            
    UNION
    SELECT 'test type 2',            as prodCategoryType
          'prod status 2'          as prodStatusType
    from dual;  

 BEGIN 
 UTL_FILE.FCLOSE_ALL; -- make sure all file handles are closed for session
 l_file := UTL_FILE.fopen(l_extract_dir , 'Sample2.dat', 'w', 32767);

 -- Create an empty XML document
  l_domdoc := dbms_xmldom.newDomDocument;

 -- Create a root node
 l_root_node := dbms_xmldom.makeNode(l_domdoc);

 -- Create a message root node
 l_message_node := dbms_xmldom.appendChild( l_root_node, dbms_xmldom.makeNode(dbms_xmldom.createElement(l_domdoc, 'message' ))
                                     );     

FOR production_rec in c_production LOOP

   l_production_element := dbms_xmldom.createElement(l_domdoc, 'production' );
   l_production_node    := dbms_xmldom.appendChild(l_message_node,dbms_xmldom.makeNode(l_production_element));  

    -- prodCategoryType
     l_prod_element := dbms_xmldom.createElement(l_domdoc, 'prodCategoryType' );
     l_prod_node   := dbms_xmldom.appendChild(l_production_node,dbms_xmldom.makeNode(l_prod_element));
     l_prod_text    := dbms_xmldom.createTextNode(l_domdoc, production_rec.prodCategoryType );
     l_prod_t_node   := dbms_xmldom.appendChild(l_prod_node,dbms_xmldom.makeNode(l_prod_text));

    -- prodStatusType
     l_prod_element := dbms_xmldom.createElement(l_domdoc, 'prodStatusType');
     l_prod_node    := dbms_xmldom.appendChild(l_production_node,dbms_xmldom.makeNode(l_prod_element));
     l_prod_text    := dbms_xmldom.createTextNode(l_domdoc, production_rec.prodStatusType);
     l_prod_t_node   := dbms_xmldom.appendChild(l_prod_node,dbms_xmldom.makeNode(l_prod_text));


        l_xmltype   := dbms_xmldom.getXmlType(l_domdoc);
        l_clob      := l_xmltype.getClobVal;   
        DBMS_LOB.read (l_clob, l_amount, l_pos, l_buffer);
        UTL_FILE.put(l_file, l_buffer);
        l_pos := l_pos + l_amount;

  END LOOP;

 dbms_xmldom.freeDocument(l_domdoc);
 UTL_FILE.fclose(l_file);

END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing two things wrong really. Well, three. The output you're expecting isn't valid XML as there is no root node; from earlier questions you may have just omitted that (AV-XML?) but it isn't clear.

What you're actually generating is valid though, but not in the format you expect. After the first iteration of the loop `l_xmltype` contains:

```
<message>
  <production>
    <prodCategoryType>test type 1</prodCategoryType>
    <prodStatusType>prod status 1</prodStatusType>
  </production>
</message>
```

... which is what you expect. But after the second loop, the second production node is inserted under the same message node, so you have:

```
<message>
  <production>
    <prodCategoryType>test type 1</prodCategoryType>
    <prodStatusType>prod status 1</prodStatusType>
  </production>
  <production>
    <prodCategoryType>test type 2</prodCategoryType>
    <prodStatusType>prod status 2</prodStatusType>
  </production>
</message>
```

When you do the first write out to the file you leave `l_pos` sitting at the end of the closing `</message>` tag, and you're assuming you have the structure you expect to see, which means on the next loop the next char will be the start of the second `<message>` tag. But since the (single) closing tag has now moved, `l_pos` is actually now in the middle of the newly-inserted second `<production>` tag. The read picks up from that point, so from the `on>` part of that opening tag.

The main thing you should do is separate the generation of the XML from the output to the file. Have one loop to build up the DOM as you're doing, then a separate loop afterwards to write the XML out to the file:

```
...
     l_prod_t_node   := dbms_xmldom.appendChild(l_prod_node,dbms_xmldom.makeNode(l_prod_text));

     /* Remove all existing conversion/writing from the first loop
        l_xmltype   := dbms_xmldom.getXmlType(l_domdoc);
        l_clob      := l_xmltype.getClobVal;   
        DBMS_LOB.read (l_clob, l_amount, l_pos, l_buffer);
        UTL_FILE.put(l_file, l_buffer);
        l_pos := l_pos + l_amount;
     */
  END LOOP;

  WHILE l_pos <= dbms_lob.getlength(l_clob) LOOP
    DBMS_LOB.read (l_clob, l_amount, l_pos, l_buffer);
    UTL_FILE.put(l_file, l_buffer);
    UTL_FILE.fflush(l_file);
    l_pos := l_pos + l_amount;
  END LOOP;
  UTL_FILE.fclose(l_file);
END;
/
```

You will then have a file that reflects the actual XML you're generating. Then you can tweak the generation to have a different root node and add both the message and production nodes inside the loop. You can get the structure in the question just by moving the `l_message_node := ...` line into the first loop.

Comment: That's fantastic Alex Poole.

Comment: just ran it, the only problem now it gets is it's I think getting to the maximum of the clob and printing no more and partially printing half a tab see below.                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
<message>
  <production>
    <prodCategoryType>TEST1</prodCategoryType>
    <prodStatusType>TEST_1_TEST</prodStatusType>
  </production>
</message>
<message>
  <production>
    <prodCategoryType>TEST1</prodC

Comment: So I guess I need to write/append to the file every iteration of the production node node.

Comment: @ShaunKinnair - writing a CLOB out in chunks should be fine. You don't want to break that back down into nodes and write them independently. Trying to figure out what's happening; you're sure the file is truncated, it's not just how you're viewing it?

Comment: Yes, it seems to truncate I could send you a sample of the code but I can't get it all in the comment box

Comment: although I do have  
  l_file := UTL_FILE.fopen(l_extract_dir , 'Sample2.dat', 'w', 32767);
  l_pos := 1;
  l_amount := 32767;    at the top of the program

Comment: With code that generates the XML in your question, this code to write it out works fine for me. It doesn't matter that you're doing those things at the start, as long as you aren't doing anything with the file or variables inside the first (DOM-building) loop.

Comment: Thanks Alex Poole, I'm just using a simple 1..1000 for loop to write 1000 records and I guess it's getting to the max size of the clob and then just writing it to file. Just checked and placed a counter and it's record 235 it writes partially and then ending.

Comment: Max size of a CLOB is 4GB (or more), so I doubt it... but yes, I get truncation with a lot of data. I'll check and see what I've done wrong!

Comment: Just like to thank you also for your help the last few days, as you can see i'm new to XML but I'm learning a lot with your help, so once again I thank you.

Comment: I'll take another look in the morning I think it maybe something to do with what I'm doing or to do with l_pos := 1, l_amount := 32767 and UTL_FILE.put(l_file, l_buffer)

Comment: @ShaunKinnair - OK, updated with a fix. The `utl_file.put()` stops after 32k if you don't flush it, so I've added a `fflush` call. It's writing the whole file properly for me now. Sorry about that! From the docs: ["The sum of all sequential PUT calls cannot exceed 32767 without intermediate buffer flushes"](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/u_file.htm#ARPLS70940).

Comment: Your correct about Max size of a CLOB is 4GB and the file size I have created is only 34,177 bytes (34 KB) for 235 records.

Comment: BINGO.... your a star Mr Alex Poole, do I owe you... just added the fflush and it worked for a 1000 records. Great! Made my night and thank you so much.